# Missing dependencies when using yarn workspace with React native init

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces, react-native-cli

I want to setup a monorepo.
I init my React native project with `npx react-native init myProject` as the first project. (there will be more project added later)

Folder structure

- Parent

  - myProject

    - package.json (created by react-native)
  - yarn.lock
  - package.json (where I setup workspace)

Then I setup yarn workspace from the parent folder of myProject.

```
    {   "name": "Parent",   
        "private": true,   
        "workspaces": {
        "packages": [
          "*"
        ],
        "nohoist": [
          "**/react-native",
          "**/react-native-*",
          "**/@react-native-*",
          "**/@react-native-*/**",
          "**/@react-navigation",
          "**/@react-navigation/**",
          "**/hermes-engine",
          "**/rn-*"
        ]   }
     }
```

Everything seems to work until I push to git and clone back. I use `yarn install` but got this error when start the project (run android or run ios)

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `scheduler` from `node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js`: scheduler could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  ..\node_modules
```

The only way I can fix that is to cd myProject and run `npm install` (it will add some packages and the app will work) while cd and using `yarn install` won't do anything

I just want to use yarn for the project so what can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure out how to fix it. I forgot to edit metro.config in RN folder.

```
const path = require('path')

const linkedLibs = [path.resolve(__dirname, '..')]
console.info('CONFIG', linkedLibs) 
 
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
  watchFolders: linkedLibs,
};
```

Use this and everything will be fine